# Is it necessary to cap test and control metric at same percentile to treat outliers?

Tags: ab-test

I am working on an AB test and the metric I am using to compare test and control is revenue. Both of my test and control have outliers. I am trying to treat outliers and have found that to do so, I need to cap test at 99.98 percentile and control at 99.95 percentile. I need help to understand if by capping test and control at different percentile values, am I introducing bias?